# Sencha touch - change back button text for image in NavigationBar

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm usign Sencha Touch 2.1 so this code should work ([link I used for inspiration](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?188982)):

```
defaultBackButtonText: null,
        useTitleForBackButtonText: false,
        backButton: {
            // ui: 'toolbar-back',
            // align : 'left',
            iconCls: 'back',
            iconMask: true
        },
```

But I can still see icon and text as well.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use an empty string instead of null for `defaultBackButtonText`, and it removes the text (also using ST 2.1):

```
defaultBackButtonText: '',
```

EDIT: To clarify, this is an example of the full config for a nav view with a back button using an icon with no text:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.GroupNavView', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'groupnavview',

    config: {
        defaultBackButtonText: '',

        navigationBar: {
            backButton: { 
                iconCls:'arrow_left', 
                iconMask: true,
                ui: 'dark',
                cls: 'backButton'
            }
        },

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'mylist'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't make it an image

Comment: The question stated that the icon is already visible, he just needed to hide the text. That is what this does.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Yes, I've tried empty string as well. Haven't succeeded.

Comment: The above setup definitely works for me in ST 2.1. I would just check that you put everything in the right place (e.g. notice that `defaultBackButtonText` is a config on the view itself, not on the navigationBar).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no "`back`" iconCls available in the default theme. Try using some other icon like "`home`". Also, you missed the `navigationBar` config. It should be like this:

```
defaultBackButtonText : null,
navigationBar: {
  backButton : {
    align : 'left',
    iconCls: 'home',
    iconMask: true,
    ui : 'plain'
  }
},
```

As I tested, I see only home icon there - nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've tried this, but I see home icon and "Back". "back" is my custom icon.

Comment: Then use defaultBackButtonText  : '' instead of null. That should work.